# Why MediaDevices.ondevicechange event doesn't trigger when a new Bluetooth device is paired?

Tags: bluetooth, webrtc, event-listener, mediastream, mediadevices

I have been working on a conference calling web application and I am using media-stream-api. When someone plugs in their USB camera the `navigator.mediaDevices.ondevicechange` gets triggered but it doesn't trigger for a Bluetooth device.

so the following code is working for me when I use a USB device.

`navigator.mediaDevices.addEventListener('devicechange', this.getDeviceList);`

Can someone explain why the above event listener doesn't trigger for a BlueTooth device?

Comment: I used this [reference code](https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/) from [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/ondevicechange) and it could detect my bluetooth device change. As soon as I connected a bluetooth audio headset it updates the list and when I disconnect the headset it remove the bluetooth audio headset from the list. I am using mac and my browser version is `Chrome 75.0.3770.142 stable`.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.10 and my browser version is ```Chrome Version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit)```

But if it's working with you, then I'll try it on a mac and a windows pc and see how it works.